# How to solve diamond issue in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, name-collision

I have following test program

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class Faculty {
// data members of Faculty
public:
    Faculty(int x) {
    cout<<"Faculty::Faculty(int ) called"<< endl;
    }
    void test() {
        cout<<"Faculty::test called" << endl;
    }
};

class Student  {
// data members of Student
public:
    Student(int x) {
        cout<<"Student::Student(int ) called"<< endl;
    }
    void test() {
        cout<<"Student::test called" << endl;
    }
};

class TA : virtual public Faculty, virtual public Student {
public:
    TA(int x):Student(x), Faculty(x) {
        cout<<"TA::TA(int ) called"<< endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    TA ta1(30);
    ta1.test();
}
```

An errors is getting during compilation

```
8be257447d8c26ef785b1a60f2884a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
748be257447d8c26ef785b1a60f2884a.cpp:36:6: error: request for member 'test' is ambiguous
  ta1.test();
      ^
748be257447d8c26ef785b1a60f2884a.cpp:22:7: note: candidates are: void Student::test()
  void test() {
       ^
748be257447d8c26ef785b1a60f2884a.cpp:11:7: note:                 void Faculty::test()
  void test() {
       ^
```

Even I'm using virtual inheritance here. Any solution to this?

Comment: There's no diamond here. You just have a name clash from two unrelated base classes, and virtual inheritance cannot do anything about that. Don't throw solutions you don't understand to unrelated problems.

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: Try to use `ta1.Student::test()` or `ta1.Faculty::test()`

Comment: Wrong tag, no diamond-problem in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of `virtual` keyword here, classes `Student` and `Faculty` are not related via inheritance from common class.

If you want specific method to be used in `TA` you can put `using Student::test;` or `using Faculty::test;` inside `TA` class declaration.

I hope that this example appeared from purely educational purposes, because if it's used/planned to be used in real application - it's a sign of something's going wrong with design :)

Answer (score 0):

You simply have two `test()` methods in your `TA` class, one inherited from `Faculty`, the other one from `Student`, and compiler correctly informs you it can't decide which one you want to call.

You need to resolve that either by saying explicitly which method you want to invoke:

```
TA ta1(30);
ta1.Faculty::test();
```

or how the object should be treated (and that will imply which method to call):

```
((Faculty &)ta1).test();
```